# rand() not generating random numbers even after srand(time(NULL))

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call a class function using a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Basket.getLemonNum(); i++)
{
    lemonWeights[i] = Fruit.generateWeight(fruit, fruitWeight);
    cout << lemonWeights[i] << " ";
}
```

This goes to the Fruit class to it's member function generateWeight():

```
   int fruitClass::generateWeight(char fruitN, int& fruitW)
    {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int weight = 0;

    switch (fruitName)
    {
    case 'a':
        weight = rand() % 500 + 100;
        return fruitW = weight;
        break;
    case 'l':
        weight = rand() % 400 + 300; 
        return fruitW = weight;
        break;
    case 'w':
        weight = rand() % 1000 + 800; 
        return fruitW = weight;
        break;
    }
} 



Output:
128 128 128 128
```

but it's generating the same number all the time, even when I use a different function to call it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Basket.getWatermelonNum(); i++)
{
    watermelonWeights[i] = Fruit.generateWeight(fruit, fruitWeight);
    cout << watermelonWeights[i] << " ";

}

Output:
128 128 128
```

As you can see, I did seed srand().
Also, the header files  and  are included.
What is going on?

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: Using `srand()` in loop might not good, and in this case it *is* wrong.

Comment: Although not critical here, it is worth noting that rand() is not a particularly good pseudorandom number generator. Take a look at things like std::mt19937

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call `srand()` once, whereas you call it on every entry into `generateWeight()`. Since nowadays computers are fast and `time()` returns the time in seconds, this mostly restarts the random number generator from the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize the pseudo random number generator seed again and again with the same seed (the time which has not changed since the last call since CPUs are very fast today) and, thus, you always get the same "random" number.

Generelly, 1) don't use srand() in a loop and 2) rand() has several defects as it does not generate nicely distributed random numbers (nice video about this [rand() considered harmful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY))

Instead of rand() you should use [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) (requires C++11):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```